# Como abrir no tamanho original uma imagem que está dentro de um ImageView?

Tags: android

Eu tenho algumas imagens dentro de imageView, e  precisava abrir estas imagens no tamanho original quando clicar sobre elas. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "abrir"?

Comment: clicar sobre ela.

Comment: Você clica e depois? Como vai apresentá-la?

Comment: Eu achei que tinha classe pronta do Android para tratar isso, mas vou ter que pegar a ImageView clicada e mandar para uma activity com um layout grande.

Comment: Eu faço isso mesmo, abro em uma activity apenas para exibir a imagem.

Comment: e para dar zoom na imagem? como você faz? estou procurando isso agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque essa propriedade no seu ImageView

> android:scaleType="center"

Informações sobre [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: o "CENTER_INSIDE"  funcionou como eu precisava, mas vlw

Comment: @daniel12345smith `CENTER_INSIDE` não apresenta a imagem com o tamanho original, ele a redimensiona para as dimensões da *ImageView*

Comment: Sim, mas como eu coloquei a imageView dentro de um layout do tamanho da tela ficou a mesma coisa que utilizar o "wrap_content". Mas obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 2):

Os atributos definidos na *ImageView* é que irão determinar o tamanho da imagem.
A forma de ela ser apresentada, redimensionada(scaled) ou cortada, irá depender do atributo `android:scaleType`.

No entanto, quando a quiser apresentar no tamanho original os atributos que definem o comprimento e largura devem ser declarados como `wrap_content`

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```